# Load Different Angularjs apps using single spa

Tags: angularjs, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I have implemented single spa with angular 9 and followed below link
https://github.com/liuyiba/Single-spa-angular-cross-domain. It is based on coexist apps. My need is to inject one angular app into another angular app [container app] and both are based on different domain.

I have 2 websites like abc.com and xyz.com and want to call abc.com from xyz.com link. I used system.js to import abc.com but it throws cors error although I have created proxy.config to avoid cors.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem... I cant find any fix for this problem... the only thing that solves it in my case is to run the angularjs code with the angular13(with single-spa) within the same project(I put in the '/assets/' folder), then they are in the same domain... but thats not a fix...it's a workaround Im not proud of...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).